# crash: Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is UISearchController

Tags: ios, crash, presentmodalviewcontroller

I face a crash three times on fabirc. Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is .

```
0   CoreFoundation  __exceptionPreprocess
1   libobjc.A.dylib objc_exception_throw
2   UIKitCore   __78-[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:]_block_invoke
3   UIKitCore   __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke_2
4   UIKitCore   +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:]
5   UIKitCore   __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke
6   UIKitCore   -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:]
7   UIKitCore   -[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]
8   UIKitCore   -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]
9   UIKitCore   __51-[UISearchController _performAutomaticPresentation]_block_invoke
10  UIKitCore   -[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:]
11  UIKitCore   -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext _runAlongsideCompletions]
12  UIKitCore   -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:]
13  UIKitCore   -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:]
14  UIKitCore   __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke
15  UIKitCore   +[UIViewController _scheduleTransition:]
16  UIKitCore   -[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]
17  UIKitCore   -[UIPresentationController _dismissWithAnimationController:interactionController:target:didEndSelector:]
18  UIKitCore   __99-[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithAnimationController:interactionController:completion:]_block_invoke_2
19  UIKitCore   +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:]
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @zaitsman It's not settled yet. But I think what caused the crash was that the controller with UISearchBar didn't dealloc.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!viewControllerToPresent.isBeingPresented) {
     //present the view controller
} else {
     //if you present viewControllerToPresent at this place then the app will 
    //crash
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that it occurs only on iOS 13 and in the following situation:

after closing searchcontrolle

```
searchController.isActive = false
```

the crash will happen when activating

```
searchController.isActive = true
```

The workaround for activation is following

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    searchController?.searchBar.searchTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
} else {
    searchController?.isActive = true
}
```